# Django: проверка на только что созданный товар

Tags: python, django

Есть модель `products`. Когда выбираешь товар, изменяешь его и сохраняешь, то выполняется метод `save`. А когда создаешь новый товар, то тоже выполняется метод `save`. Как можно сделать проверку, что товар был только что создан, либо же его просто изменили?

Пример:

```py
class Products(models.Model):
    ...
    
    def save():
        if какая-то проверка:
            print('Товар только что создан!')
        else:
            print('Товар был изменен!')
```

Либо же есть какая-то специальная функция?

Comment: метод save() должен выполнять только свою конкретную задачу - сохранять объект. Логику, которую вы хотите туда засунуть, лучше выполнять во вью-фукнции, сериализаторе или форме.

Comment: Просто есть такой вариант или нет? Можно так сделать?

Comment: Можно все, а нужно ли. 
`pk`/`id` у модели будет None, если объект новый, и еще не в бд

Comment: @ZaArs если первичный ключ не AutoField, то он может оказаться не None, так что в общем случае полагаться на это не стоит